# How can I make MediaPlayer sound to be continued? Not looping

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have a MediaPlayer for `onTouchEvent()`. So every time when I touch the screen its play the sound for two seconds. The problem is, even I continued touching on the screen, I still have to wait until the program finish the first two seconds sound then play it next time.

But I want it to be like every time I touch the screen, no matter the sound from first tap is playing or not, it have to play a new sound.

Here is the code I have:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                MediaPlayer sound= MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.boo);
                sound.start();
                pointX.add(event.getX());
                pointY.add(event.getY());
                postInvalidate();
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether there is an instance of mediaPlayer if yes you need to stop it and play it again

```
MediaPlayer sound;
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (sound != null) {
                sound.stop();
                sound.release();
                sound = null;
           }
           sound = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.boo);
                    sound.start();
                    pointX.add(event.getX());
                    pointY.add(event.getY());
                    postInvalidate();
                    break;
```

Comment: I change to SoundPool... Seems easy